# How to clear navigation history in Angular router

Tags: angular

I have a use case, in which I need to clear the navigation history using `angular-router` (so that hardware back button press does not take me to the previous page but homepage).

I have been looking around for a straightforward solution for this but haven't found any.

I have suggestions of using `nativescript` but I don't want to increase my bundle-size for this requirement.

Please advise if there is any in-built `angular` functionality I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I was able to make it work was by using NavContoller

```
   this.nav.navigateRoot('/tabs/home');
```

This removed all the pages from the stack and navigated to the homepage

Comment: This did not work for me with Ionic 5

Comment: @TheTom If, like me, you would have like to have this configuration to avoid the user getting back to the login page, using a guard will do the trick

Comment: @RaphaëlBalet, so you're saying this and route guard together will do?

Comment: @TheTom Nope, I'm saying just the route and done. Then the guard won't let you come back the the page you where and it will look like your at the root of the app again.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it in two ways. If you don't need a state in the history then you can use something like this:

```
this.router.navigate([`/myPage/`], { relativeTo: this.route, skipLocationChange: true });
```

Or if you just want to replace current state in a history with a new one:

```
this.router.navigate(['/home'], {replaceUrl: true});
```

Comment: replaceUrl would just When true, navigates while replacing the current state in history.
This means when i press back i go to the previous page. Instead, I want to remove all previous navigation history, and simply navigate to the root

Comment: yes, that I already mentioned, and what about the first code snippet?

Comment: this.router.navigate(["booking-details"], {
        relativeTo: this.route, skipLocationChange: true,
        queryParams: {
          caller: 'review-booking',
          bookingId: res.bookingId,
          flow: 'booking'
        }
      });

After adding these the navigation itself was not happening

Answer (score 0):

> import { Location } from '@angular/common';
> URL is your '/tabs/home'
> const URL = '/tabs/home'
> this.location.replaceState(URL)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!